# Getting multiple and duplicate values after maping an array prop and then passing the maped value as prop to another component in React

Tags: reactjs, components, mapping, rendering, react-props

I am using React with material ui and I am getting this strange bug.

I have a parent Orders page, and then passing an array of orders to the orders component like this:

```
      <PendingComponent
            {...{pendingOrders}} />
```

And then in the PendingComponent I am maping the orders array like this:

```
      <Box m="1rem 0 0 0">
      {pendingOrders?.map((order, index) => (
        <Accordion
          key={index}
```

Inside this Accordion, there is another component, a modal which I am passing the order as a prop to it like this:

```
    {updateSatus && (
                <UpdateOrderStatusModal {...{ order }} />
    )}
```

Now when I try to access the order values in the UpdateOrderStatusModal component that's where there strange thing is happing, I am not getting the correct value of the mapped order value I should be expecting.

Like this, In the PendingComponent component I am currently mapping just 3 orders, and then passing an order to UpdateOrderStatusModal component, Instead of getting a single order, they are all being printed one after each other when I console log, and I am unable to get the actual order I am targeting to get in the UpdateOrderStatusModal:

```
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'enoch@myemail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 6:14 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'enoch@myemail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 6:14 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'admin@mail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 5:15 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'admin@mail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 5:15 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'the@mail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 5:08 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
UpdateOrderStatusModal.jsx:27 The order in the modal {status: 'pending', userEmail: 'the@mail.com', dateCreated: 'Wed, August 16, 2023 at 5:08 PM', step: 0, orderProducts: {…}, …}
```

What React rules am I breaking? Why am I getting this behaviour?
Thank you.

***UPDATE - Detailed reproducible code***

I recreated the same problem in a different project and got the same problem. Here is the code for the component.

I have a favourites products page for the user after adding some items to favourites:

```
     <ul
                              role="list"
                              className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-200"
                            >
                              {products.map((product) => (
                                <li key={product.id} className="flex py-6">
                                  <div
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      setOpenFavourites(false);
                                      navigate(`/product/${product.id}`);
                                    }}
                                    className="hover:cursor-pointer h-24 w-24 flex-shrink-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md border border-gray-200"
                                  >
                                    <img
                                      src={product.images[0]}
                                      alt={product.imageAlt}
                                      className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
                                    />
                                  </div>

                                  <div className="ml-4 flex flex-1 flex-col">
                                    <div>
                                      <div className="flex justify-between text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                        <h3>
                                          <button
                                            onClick={() => {
                                              setOpenFavourites(false);
                                              navigate(
                                                `/product/${product.id}`
                                              );
                                            }}
                                          >
                                            {product.name}
                                          </button>
                                        </h3>
                                        <p className="ml-4">
                                          $ {product.price}
                                        </p>
                                      </div>
                                      <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                        {product.availability}
                                      </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex flex-1 items-end justify-between text-sm">
                                      <p className="text-gray-500">
                                        Min Order{" "}
                                        <span className="text-gray-800">
                                          {product.minOrder} Tonne
                                        </span>
                                      </p>

                                      <div className="flex">
                                        <button
                                          type="button"
                                          onClick={() =>
                                            handleRemove(product.id)
                                          }
                                          className="font-medium text-primary hover:text-secondary"
                                        >
                                          Remove
                                        </button>
                                      </div>

                                      <div className="flex">
                                        <button
                                          type="button"
                                          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                                          className="font-medium text-primary hover:text-secondary"
                                        >
                                          Open this Modal
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                          {open && (<TestModal product={product} />)}
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </li>
                              ))}
                            </ul>
```

In the code above, if at the botton there is the testing button "Open this Modal" and the TestModal below it, passing the maped product as a prop to it.

Now this is the TestModal code:

```
import React from 'react'

const TestModal = ({product}) => {

    console.log("test modal mounted", product.name)

    const investigate = () => {
        console.log("investigate clicked", product.name, product.id)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                <div className="relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl">
                    <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none">

                        <div
                            className="
                     items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b"
                        >
                            <button
                                className="text-red-500 background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-2 text-sm outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                                type="button"
                            onClick={investigate}
                            >
                                Investigate
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
        </>
    )
}

export default TestModal
```

Now on this modal, let's say I clicked the "Open this modal" on a Potatoes product, in the Test Modal when I click the "Investigate" button, I am expecting the Potato product informotion to be console logged in that investigate function, but that is not happeing, I am getting a different product infomation printed, like Strawberry if I have strawbery as one of the product in my favourites, likes it's alway picking the product that is at the bottom of the mapped array and not the one that I actually clicked on.

I have also noticed this behaviour is happening when I use a modal,a modal component that's displaying on top of other component, when I use a component that doesn't have some kind of z index property it's not doing that strange behaviour.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Seems there is a different issue (whereas the original as was why console logged something twice), regardless --

I tried to reproduce your newly provided code in CodeSandbox, but wasn't able to reproduce it. Can you take a look and see what I am missing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cherry-943s99?file=/src/App.tsx

---

I do not see anything wrong with your code (especially since the info is limited...). However, according to what you said --

> ...they are all being printed one after each other when I console log

Assuming you are using strict mode in a development environment, that is completely normal. Re-rendering twice during the initial render supposedly help you find bug quicker, and React only does that in development mode.

> Components breaking this rule behave unpredictably and cause bugs. To help you find accidentally impure code, Strict Mode calls some of your functions (only the ones that should be pure) twice in development.

https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

Comment: Okay thank you, I tried removing the StrictMode temporarily but nothing changed. Just to summarise the problem again, lets say on the Accordion with an order X, when I open the UpdateOrderStatusModal component on  that Accordion I am expecting to be getting the value of X only in that accordion, even if it gets rendered 2 or 3 times that is not a problem at all, the problem is I am not getting the value of X alone rendered in this Modal, all the orders I am maping are being rendered, and then when I try to run a function for the order X in the accordion it's not even using the info of order X.

Comment: What more information would you need so that I can give you?

Comment: Ideally the entire code, but a minimum reproducible code would be nice, too.

Comment: Hi @taiwei-tuan, I updated the question with some more information.

Comment: I reproduced the problem in codesendbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modest-montalcini-fkkl96). I think you didn't reproduce the problem because the Modal have to be an actual modal as I highlighted in the update to the question, at least that's what I observed. In that sendbox code you will see that when you investigate product one, it will be showing info for product 3